# Unnamed namespace and default function arguments

Tags: c++, namespaces, default-parameters

I was wondering, how I could set a const member variable of an unnamed namespace as a default function parameter where the function is declared in an named namespace. 
Well I guess this is hard to explain for me, here is an example of what I want to do:

```
//foo.h
namespace foo
{
    void justAFunction(std::string function_string = unnamed_str);
}

//foo.cpp
#include "foo.h"

namespace foo
{
    namespace
    {
        const std::string unnamed_str = "simple string";
    } 

    void justAFunction(std::string function_string)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

This does not link...

I could still write the default parameter in the function definition, but that is not what I want, since the caller won't see it, right?
Any advice how to code this correct?

Comment: Anything defined in an unnamed namespace does not have external linkage. You cannot access such variables outside of the file they were declared in.  Any value you want to use as a default parameter to a function must be visible to that function, so there cannot be any way to hide the default value from callers of that function. You might as well write the default parameter in the function definition.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So there is no solution for this situation without placing the unnamed namespace in the header file or write the default argument in the function definition. But if I implement the latter, callers of that function will not even know that it has a default argument... and isn't this considered as bad practice? Would the better solution in this particular case be making a class instead of the namespace and setting everything static? Thanks